# Option value is not appearing when selected in drop down box

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to troubleshoot a problem which I am unable to solve. The issue is that I have a dropdown box with a select tag with some menu items in it. When I click one of the menu items the value is not appearing in the select box and its just empty. However when I console log the selected item I can see what I am selecting which is the menu item. Heres the code:

```
<Select labelId="demo-simple-select-label" id="demo-simple-select" value={selectedMake} onChange={handleMake}>
              {console.log(makes)}
              {makes &&
                makes.map((select, key) => (
                  <MenuItem key={key} value={select}>
                      {console.log(select)}
                    {select.name}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
```

If you're wondering what is "makes", it is just this:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "Honda", id: "5de9c553bce4b703a335c204"}
1: {name: "Toyota", id: "5e4dfbee2d445b7525414c1f"}
2: {name: "Suzuki", id: "5e4e00732d445b7525414c46"}
```

Im not sure why the when Honda is selected for example it is not showing in the box. I reckon it might be something to do with the id. Do let me know how to solve this problem.

This is the handleMake function as well, it is a function that is passed in as a prop from another file:

```
handleMake = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedMake: event.target.value.name,
      selectedMakeId: event.target.value.id,
    });
  };
```

Comment: try to pass select.id as a value <MenuItem key={key} value={select.id}>

Comment: @WilliamWang Did that, still not showing the value

Comment: You have to return the <MenuItem>. Use `return` before <MenuItem> along with passing value={select.id}

Comment: Objects can't be the value of a select option, you'll need to use either the `name` or `id` property. Can you provide a more complete code example? What is `handleMake` doing with the `onChange` event object? What/where is the value `selectedMake` defined and updated?

Comment: @Akankshasingh `<MenuItem />` is returned. It's an implicit return from an arrow function.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @DrewReese I edited my post with the things you requested, u can have a look now.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

Objects cannot be the value of a select option, it must be a non-object value. In your you are setting the option value to the entire "make`object, but setting the`Select`value to *just* the make's`name` property, which will never match.

```
handleMake = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    selectedMake: event.target.value.name, // <-- make's name
    selectedMakeId: event.target.value.id,
  });
};

...

<Select
  labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
  id="demo-simple-select"
  value={selectedMake} // <-- only a make's name
  onChange={handleMake}
>
  {makes.map((select, key) => (
    <MenuItem key={key} value={select}> // <-- entire make object!
      {select.name}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

## Solution

I suggest storing the selected index or `id` in state instead.

There is no need to duplicate so much data into state as you can easily derive the car make and id from a stored array index or search using the id. If you used data from one of the make objects then you'd need to search the `makes` array each time (`O(n)` linear time) to find a match, but by using the index you can get just the make object needed in `O(1)` constant time.

```
handleMake = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    selectedMake: event.target.value,
  });
};

...

<Select
  labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
  id="demo-simple-select"
  value={this.state.selectedMake} // <-- value is "index"
  onChange={this.handleMake}
>
  {makes.map((make, index) => (
    <MenuItem key={index} value={index}> // <-- pass index as "value"
      {make.name}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

To handle using the `selectedMake`, for example, if `selectedMake` === `0`:

```
makes[selectedMake] // { name: "Honda", id: "5de9c553bce4b703a335c204"}
```

Example Component

[image: Edit option-value-is-not-appearing-when-selected-in-drop-down-box]

```
function App() {
  const [selectedMake, setSelectedMake] = useState(-1);

  const changeHandler = (e) => setSelectedMake(e.target.value);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedMake, makes[selectedMake]);
  }, [selectedMake]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select value={selectedMake} onChange={changeHandler}>
        <option disabled value={-1}>
          Make
        </option>
        {makes.map((make, i) => (
          <option key={make.id} value={i}>
            {make.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what do you mean when u said this "I suggest storing the selected index or id in state instead."?

Comment: @JacksonEtherchainStake There is no need to duplicate so much data into state as you can easily derive the car make and id from a stored array index or search using the id. If you used data from one of the make objects then you'd need to search the `makes` array each time (`O(n)` linear time) to find a match, but by using the index you can get just the make object needed in `O(1)` constant time.